# Folder ist not created in Android 6.0.1 but working on Androd 5 and Android 10 to?

Tags: android, android-studio, file-handling, android-external-storage

i got a really crazy issue... I have to create a lot of folders for my application and it is working on Android 5, 7 and 10 but i have a smartphone running on Android 6.0.1 and this is showing up some problems.
It doesn't create any folder in internal storage...

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    s_mainfolder = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/Holzwurm";
    f_mainfolder = new File(s_mainfolder);
    if (!f_mainfolder.exists()) {
        f_mainfolder.mkdirs();
    }
}
else {
    s_mainfolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Holzwurm";
    f_mainfolder = new File(s_mainfolder);
    if (!f_mainfolder.exists()) {
        f_mainfolder.mkdirs();
    }
}
```

Here is the code.

Fun fact. If i just create a folder by:

```
String path = getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + "/Holzwurm";
File f_folder = new File(path);
if (!f_folder.exists()) {
    f_folder.mkdirs();
}
```

it is created. But i don't see any mistake in my if-clause?

Comment: You should start to check the return value of mkdirs() and handle accordingly.

Comment: sorry i copied the wrong code parts... this if has an else...

Comment: Better: `mainfolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Holzwurm");`

Comment: do you think that this would change my problem?

Comment: No. But it would be cleaner code.

Comment: You should fix that mkdirs stuff.

Comment: But i have to work with those strings later... so of course the code would be cleaner, but i would have some advantages, doing it like this.
Fixing the mkdirsh how and why?

Comment: If you have to work with a string later then use mainfolder.getAbsolutePath() then. Dont use two variables for the same thing.

Comment: Check the return value of mkdirs and stop and display a toast to the user if it returns false.

Comment: You create different directories for Q+ and below. You can not compare that with each other. So do not say that THE folder is not created.

Comment: It seems you miss requesting runtime permissions. Or something in your manifest.